# What is the name for finding biggest two multipliers of a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Excuse my English please.

I am looking for the name in Mathematics (/English) for finding the biggest two numbers that form an array that can contain at minimum `x number of items` whereby array's both sides are as close as possible (to form a square or square-ish rectangle).

Ex:

For 10, it is `3*4` (not `2*5` as it is not square-ish)

90 is `9*10`
91..99 is `10*10`

66 is `6*7`

or 1324 is `36*37`

Given a number, I would like to create an x*y "array", as square looking as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a word for this, though I could certainly be wrong about that.  However, a way to characterize what you want is, for any n, you want to find integers p and q such that p*q = n and |p-q| is as small as possible.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "form a number"? $3*4$ is certainly not $10$, so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood, updated the Question. Thanks!

Comment: Should be the smallest numbers, no? Otherwise, for $10$, I could choose $4\times 4$, or $1984\times 1984$,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for $k^2 + 1, \ldots, k^2 + k,$ you use $k$ by $k+1$

for $k^2 + k + 1, \ldots, k^2 + 2 k + 1,$ you use $k+1$ by $k+1$

The array dimensions for your integer $x$ are thus
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt x \right\rfloor   $$
by $$ \left\lceil \sqrt x \right\rceil  $$

```
x  floor (0.5 + sqrt(x))  ceil( sqrt (x))  
1                1               1
2                1               2
3                2               2
4                2               2
5                2               3
6                2               3
7                3               3
8                3               3
9                3               3
10                3               4
11                3               4
12                3               4
13                4               4
14                4               4
15                4               4
16                4               4
17                4               5
18                4               5
19                4               5
20                4               5
21                5               5
22                5               5
23                5               5
24                5               5
25                5               5
26                5               6
27                5               6
28                5               6
29                5               6
30                5               6
31                6               6
32                6               6
33                6               6
34                6               6
35                6               6
36                6               6
37                6               7
38                6               7
39                6               7
40                6               7
41                6               7
42                6               7
43                7               7
44                7               7
45                7               7
46                7               7
47                7               7
48                7               7
49                7               7
50                7               8
51                7               8
52                7               8
53                7               8
54                7               8
55                7               8
56                7               8
57                8               8
58                8               8
59                8               8
60                8               8
61                8               8
62                8               8
63                8               8
64                8               8
65                8               9
66                8               9
67                8               9
68                8               9
69                8               9
70                8               9
71                8               9
72                8               9
73                9               9
74                9               9
75                9               9
76                9               9
77                9               9
78                9               9
79                9               9
80                9               9
81                9               9
82                9               10
83                9               10
84                9               10
85                9               10
86                9               10
87                9               10
88                9               10
89                9               10
90                9               10
91                10               10
92                10               10
93                10               10
94                10               10
95                10               10
96                10               10
97                10               10
98                10               10
99                10               10
100                10               10
101                10               11
102                10               11
103                10               11
104                10               11
105                10               11
106                10               11
107                10               11
108                10               11
109                10               11
110                10               11
111                11               11
112                11               11
113                11               11
114                11               11
115                11               11
116                11               11
117                11               11
118                11               11
119                11               11
120                11               11
121                11               11
x    floor (0.5 + sqrt(x))   ceil( sqrt (x)) 
------------------------------------------------
```

==

Comment: This is amazing @WillyJagy! Thank you. How did you figure this out? I mean, what is the chain of thought that leads to solution of such a problem.

Comment: @Phil, mostly completing the square: $\left(k + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = k^2 + k + \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific word for this, but it seems like you're describing using square roots with a little bit of rounding if necessary. Based on the examples given (excluding $66 = 6 \times 7$: this seems out of place) you could either try $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor \times \lceil \sqrt n \rceil $ or $\lceil \sqrt n \rceil \times \lceil \sqrt n \rceil$, whichever is closer. The first may work if it's $ \ge n$, the second will always be $\ge n$.

Comment: How can I formulate this to find the numbers from a given array-item-size? (example: 1234)

Comment: @Phil You would try $\lfloor \sqrt{1234}\rfloor \times \lceil \sqrt {1234}\rceil$ or $\lceil \sqrt{1234} \rceil \times \lceil \sqrt{ 1234} \rceil$, whichever is closer but greater to $1234$.